# Buildozer SyntaxWarning in KivyMD package file

Tags: python, android, syntax, kivy, buildozer

i got a problem when compiling app with buildozer. It throws SyntaxWarning when i compile it. Since this warning is not caused by my code but rather KiyvMD package code I'm not able to suppress this warning directly as every time i edit something in the problematic file it restores its previous condition when running buildozer. Here's the error message:

```
    /home/michael/Desktop/YouTubeApp/.buildozer/android/app/kivymd/uix/picker.py:479: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
op = 1 if operation is "next" else -1
WARNING: Received a --sdk argument, but this argument is deprecated and does nothing.
No setup.py/pyproject.toml used, copying full private data into .apk.
Error while running "/home/michael/Desktop/YouTubeApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/python3 -OO -m compileall -b -f /home/michael/Desktop/YouTubeApp/.buildozer/android/app"
```

i've tried: editing picker.py file by adding another "=" in problematic line, editing picker.py by importing warnings and making it ignore SyntaxWarnings, editing picker.py and deleting pyc file.

Nothing seem to work as it always restores to an initial condition and deletes all changes.

here's the full error message

```
Compiling '/home/michael/Desktop/YouTubeApp/.buildozer/android/app/sitecustomize.py'...
/home/michael/Desktop/YouTubeApp/.buildozer/android/app/kivymd/uix/picker.py:479: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
op = 1 if operation is "next" else -1
WARNING: Received a --sdk argument, but this argument is deprecated and does nothing.
No setup.py/pyproject.toml used, copying full private data into .apk.
Error while running "/home/michael/Desktop/YouTubeApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/python3 -OO -m compileall -b -f /home/michael/Desktop/YouTubeApp/.buildozer/android/app"
This probably means one of your Python files has a syntax error, see logs above    
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain apk --debug --bootstrap=sdl2 --dist_name YTApp --name YTApp --version 0.1 --package org.test.ytapp --minsdk 21 --ndk-api 21 --private /home/michael/Desktop/YouTubeApp/.buildozer/android/app --permission INTERNET --permission ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION --permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION --permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE --permission READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE --android-entrypoint org.kivy.android.PythonActivity --android-apptheme @android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar --orientation portrait --window --copy-libs --arch armeabi-v7a --color=always --storage-dir="/home/michael/Desktop/YouTubeApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21 --ignore-setup-py
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/michael-VirtualBox:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/859,unix/michael-VirtualBox:/tmp/.ICE-unix/859'
#     WINDOWID = '58720259'
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu:/etc/xdg:/etc/xdg'
#     XDG_SESSION_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'xfce-'
#     CLUTTER_BACKEND = 'x11'
#     LANGUAGE = 'en_US'
#     LC_ADDRESS = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
#     LC_NAME = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'xubuntu'
#     LC_MONETARY = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
#     XDG_SEAT = 'seat0'
#     PWD = '/home/michael/Desktop/YouTubeApp'
#     LOGNAME = 'michael'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'xubuntu'
#     QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME = 'gtk2'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/home/michael/.Xauthority'
#     XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR = '/var/lib/lightdm-data/michael'
#     GDM_LANG = 'en_US'
#     HOME = '/home/michael'
#     LC_PAPER = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
#     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.webp=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'XFCE'
#     VTE_VERSION = '6203'
#     XDG_SEAT_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0'    
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     XDG_SESSION_CLASS = 'user'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     LC_IDENTIFICATION = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
#     GTK_OVERLAY_SCROLLING = '0'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     USER = 'michael'
#     DISPLAY = ':0.0'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     LC_TELEPHONE = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
#     LC_MEASUREMENT = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
#     XDG_VTNR = '7'
#     XDG_SESSION_ID = 'c2'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     LC_TIME = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/xubuntu:/usr/share/xfce4:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop:/usr/share'
#     PATH = '/home/michael/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/michael/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
#     GDMSESSION = 'xubuntu'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
#     LC_NUMERIC = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/michael/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/michael/.buildozer/android/platform  /android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/michael/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '29'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Comment: Did you tried replacing 'is' with '==' on the shown line of code? Python doesn't like comparing literals with 'is'.

Comment: sure, i've tried it. But after i edit anything in the file and start buildozer running it restores previous condition of the python script and deletes all changes i made @watney

Comment: The 'is' vs '==' is just a warning. I don't think that is your problem. Are there any other messages?

Comment: @JohnAnderson the title says he's worried about the warning

Comment: @JohnAnderson. Added the full error message

Comment: @watney i'm more worried about buildozer crashing, seeing SyntaxError right before the it crashed convinced me that problem is in this error. Would be great if i'm wrong and problem is in something else that is easy to fix.

Comment: @Michael This is just a warning and doesn't involve in bulldozer crashing, rest assured. The issue must be somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

The command that got the error is trying to compile all the `.py` files in the `/home/michael/Desktop/YouTubeApp/.buildozer/android/app` directory. I suggest doing a `cd` to that directory and looking for `.py` files that do not have a corresponding compiled file (`.pyc`). Those files would be candidates for causing the error. For each of those files, try running `python3 -OO -m compileall -b -f  <file_name>`. Hopefully, one of them will give you an error message.

Answer (score 0):

> This probably means one of your Python files has a syntax error, see logs above

The log clearly says that your python code has some syntax error. Make sure you're able to run your code without errors before trying to package them.